# Installation folder of MSSQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows

How do I find the folder path where my MSSQL server 2008 R2 is installed, inside my C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer WMI classes (`Win32_Product`, `Win32_SoftwareFeature` and `Win32_SoftwareElement`) don't provide this information: there is no requirement that there is a single location at any of those levels. Therefore something application specific is needed.

Looks like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100
```

contains `VerSpecificRootDir` with the base folder. And it looks like replacing the `100` with the correct number (ie. SQL Server version times ten) will work across versions.